# How to create a bottom Bar button in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**I'm currently developing an Android app in Flutter. How can I add a button at the bottom of the page like this:--**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This brother and customize size and color

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);
    
    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: MyWidget(),
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              height: 60,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: (){
    
                      // your code
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: 45,
                      width: 170,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [Icon(Icons.favorite_border), Text("WishList")],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: (){
                      // your code
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: 45,
                      width: 170,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            Icons.card_travel,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "  Add To Bag",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Text('Hello, World!', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try the `Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,child: RaisedButton()`